# How to change the background color of keypad in iOS 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 5 for developing applications. I want to change the color of keyboard in [iOS 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_7). I want a color like black or blue.

How can I change the color of keyboard in iOS 7?

Answer (score 23):

You can only set the keyboard appearance to any of three listed below using the [`UIKeyboardAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIKeyboardAppearance).

```
UIKeyboardAppearanceDefault  // Corresponds to the UIKeyboardAppearanceLight
UIKeyboardAppearanceDark     // Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
UIKeyboardAppearanceLight    // Available in iOS 7.0 and later.
```

There is one more constant named `UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert` but, that is now deprecated. You should use `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` instead.

You **can't** use any custom or undefined color.
So, Use ...

```
myTextfield.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

Answer (score 12):

In iOS 7, since the keyboard is translucent, I was able to accomplish this effect by adding a colored subview behind the keyboard that shows and hides with [keyboard notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957476/ios-7-keyboard-animation).

I created a [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) project to demonstrate this technique. Keep in mind it only works in portrait orientation right now and obviously only in iOS 7.

https://github.com/meekapps/TintedKeyboard

[image]

Comment: That looks, really awesome, actually!

Comment: Based on the "You can only use `UIKeyboardAppearanceDark` and `UIKeyboardAppearanceLight`" comments, I think this is the closest possible thing to answering the original question.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the color with the keyboardAppearance method.

```
_textField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceDark;
```

Have a look at the [Apple API docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/keyboardAppearance)

Comment: Thanks to all for your reply

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment of wanting a custom color:

You *could* do this... Just use the normal keyboard, then observe `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` so that you can show a color `UIView` behind the keyboard.

It would be hacky, but it would work because the default keyboard is transparent to a degree on iOS 7.

Good luck.