# iOS 7 - Keyboard animation

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, animation, keyboard, ios7

I'm trying to understand the new keyboard animation in iOS 7.0 on the iPhone 5 Simulator. I want to resize my `UITableView` when the keyboard appears, but I can't get the right animation details.
I'm using the information from the `NSNotification` object, when the keyboard appears or disappears.

Here is my log:

```
Move keyboard from {{0, 920}, {320, 216}} to {{0, 352}, {320, 216}}
 with duration: 0.400000
 and animation curve: 7

UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut = 0
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn = 1
UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut = 2
UIViewAnimationCurveLinear = 3
```

The animation curve is an unknown value, what should I do?

Comment: check if this solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313951/uitableviewcontroller-and-uitextfield-keyboard

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I'm using a `UIViewController` with a `UITableView` subview.

Comment: What animation details are you expecting?

Comment: @Krishnan not a 7, I imagine.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Now I found the solution. The animation starts from the point `{0, 920}` to `{0, 352}`. The problem was that the `UITableView` object started with a size of `{160, 568}`, so I changed the size of the `UITableView` to `{160, 920}` before the animation was started.

Concerning to the unknown animation curve, I just set the parameter to `animationCurve << 16` to convert it from a view animation curve to a view animation option.
The value is not equal to the linear, ease in, ease out and ease inout animation curve.

Here is my code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(_keyboardWillShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

and:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = aNotification.userInfo;

    //
    // Get keyboard size.

    NSValue *beginFrameValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardBeginFrame = [self.view convertRect:beginFrameValue.CGRectValue fromView:nil];

    NSValue *endFrameValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [self.view convertRect:endFrameValue.CGRectValue fromView:nil];

    //
    // Get keyboard animation.

    NSNumber *durationValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = durationValue.doubleValue;

    NSNumber *curveValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
    UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = curveValue.intValue;

    //
    // Create animation.

    CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    bTableViewFrame.size.height = (keyboardBeginFrame.origin.y - tableViewFrame.origin.y);
    self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;

    void (^animations)() = ^() {
        CGRect tableViewFrame = self.tableView.frame;
        tableViewFrame.size.height = (keyboardEndFrame.origin.y - tableViewFrame.origin.y);
        self.tableView.frame = tableViewFrame;
    };

    //
    // Begin animation.

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration
                          delay:0.0
                        options:(animationCurve << 16)
                     animations:animations
                     completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: "Concerning to the unknown animation curve, I just set the parameter to animationCurve << 16 to convert it from a view animation curve to a view animation option."
 How did you come about this?

Comment: see the definition of `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn` for example in `UIView.h`

Comment: Things like this are insanely frustrating. What the hell, Apple? Thanks.

Answer (score 72):

In iOS 7, the keyboard uses a new, undocumented animation curve. While some have noted that using an undocumented value for the animation option, I prefer to use the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

// work

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

While block based animations are the recommendation, the animation curve returned from the keyboard notification is an `UIViewAnimationCurve`, while the option you would need to pass to block based animations is an `UIViewAnimationOptions`. Using the traditional UIView animation methods allows you to pipe the value directly in. **Most importantly, this will use the new undocumented animation curve (integer value of 7) and cause the animation to match the keyboard**. And, it will work just as well on iOS 6 and 7.

Comment: Works perfectly on `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification`, but when dismissing the keyboard via `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` my UIView seems to be out of sync with the keyboard.

Comment: is it legal to use an undocumented animation curve? Will Apple reject your app if you do this?

Comment: 1) This is likely to never be caught by Apple, but in general it would be a bad idea to use it directly.
2) We aren't using it directly here. We are naively passing the value we are given.

Comment: @Piotr I've discovered than in iOS 7, when the keyboard is performing the dismiss animation, it uses the undocumented UIViewAnimationCurve with integer value of 6 instead of the value of 7 that is reported by `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey`. It's a hacky solution, but using `[UIView setAnimationCurve:6]` if the keyboard is dismissing seems to keep the UIView animation in sync.

Comment: I'd spent ages trying to get something to animate along with they keyboard properly and it never looked right until I found this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Works great for me. And in my case since I'm animating view constraints, I had to add [self.view layoutIfNeeded] for it to work;

Comment: Works great & smooth. I know we are not using undocumented api "Directly" but any of you submitted the application to AppStore with this API ? Does Apple approved it ?

Comment: This is the intended way to use that value. I have submitted several apps that use this.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `animateWithDuration` block and set curve inside it. It's clean and work well.

```
UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
double duration = [[notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                    delay:0
                  options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState 
               animations:^{
                 [UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
                 /* ANIMATION HERE */
                 // don't forget layoutIfNeeded if you use autolayout
               }
               completion:nil];
```

Happy coding!

**UPDATE**

You can use a simple UIViewController category written by me https://github.com/Just-/UIViewController-KeyboardAnimation

Answer (score 5):

Use `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification` instead, because some international keyboards, like the Chinese keyboard, change height during use. Also this code gives you the correct heights for the keyboard, even in landscape mode. (Note: the code below is for **Autolayout**)

```
//set your observer, in a method like viewDidLoad
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillChange:) name:UIKeyboardWillChangeFrameNotification object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWillChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGRect initialRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat initialHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - [self.view convertRect:initialRect fromView:nil].origin.y;
    CGRect keyboardRect = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    CGFloat newHeight = self.view.frame.size.height - [self.view convertRect:keyboardRect fromView:nil].origin.y;
    //set your constraints here, based on initialHeight and newHeight, which are the heights of the keyboard before & after animation.
    [self.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Clean. The `swift` version is here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923086/what-is-the-animation-speed-of-the-keyboard-appearing-in-ios8

Answer (score 4):

To use the same animation as keyboard has, you have to use undocumented Curve option.

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSDictionary *userInfo = [notification userInfo];

    CGRect rect = [userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = [[userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    NSInteger curve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue] << 16;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:curve animations:^{

    } completion:nil];
}
```

I found that actually method `animateWithDuration:delay:usingSpringWithDamping:initialSpringVelocity:options:animations:completion:` is the new way that all animations are done in iOS7 and iOS8 now. You just make right duration, damping and velocity and you will get the same effect, but even you can change speed/time.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4

Add observers for keyboard notifications:

- UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
- UIKeyboardDidHideNotification

via

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(_ observer: Any, 
        selector aSelector: Selector, 
        name aName: NSNotification.Name?, 
        object anObject: Any?)
```

And implement selector to animate the UI with Keyboard animation.
In order to create a valid curve value we need to shift UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey by << 16

```
func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification!) {
    if let info = notification.userInfo {
        let keyboardSize = info[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? CGRect
        let duration = info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double 
        let curveVal = (info[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.intValue ?? 7 // default value for keyboard animation
        let options = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curveVal << 16))
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: options, animations: {
        // any operation to be performed
    }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 13 you are in an implicit animation, so just modify your layout inside your notification handler and it will animate with the correct duration and curve.

Answer (score 0):

**Register for the notification:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

**Respond by animating a change to the frame.origin.y of the view.**

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = aNotification.userInfo;
    NSValue *endFrameValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [self.view convertRect:endFrameValue.CGRectValue fromView:nil];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[aNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[aNotification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

    CGRect searchButtonFrame = self.searchButton.frame;
    searchButtonFrame.origin.y = (keyboardEndFrame.origin.y - searchButtonFrame.size.height);
    self.searchButton.frame = searchButtonFrame;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```