# What is the animation speed of the keyboard appearing in iOS8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios8

The following is an animation for a textField and toolBar which move upward when the keyboard appears.

```
    baseConstraint.constant = 211
    self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.30, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
```

It is close but not quite identical. How would you modify the above animation?

Edit:

Here is the final code using the answer below!

```
   func keyboardWillShow(aNotification: NSNotification)    {

        let duration = aNotification.userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey) as Double
        let curve = aNotification.userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey) as UInt

        self.view.setNeedsLayout()
        baseConstraint.constant = 211
        self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

        UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.fromMask(curve), animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {
        (value: Bool) in println()
        })
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can get the animation duration and the animation curve from the userInfo dictionary on the keyboardWillShow: notifications.

First register for the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
```

Then get the values from the notifications userInfo keys.

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSNumber *duration = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
    NSNumber *curve = [notification.userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];

   // Do stuff with these values.
}
```

There are a lot more of these keys, and you can also get them from the UIKeyboardWillDismiss notification.

This functionality is available all the way back to iOS 3.0 :D

Heres the docs:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621576-keyboardwillshownotification

Swift Version

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
    let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
}
```

Updated for latest swift version

```swift
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)

private func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    let animationDuration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double
    let animationCurve = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
    guard let duration = animationDuration, let curve = animationCurve else {
        // values weren't available
        return
    }
    let curveAnimationOption = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: curve.uintValue)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: curveAnimationOption, animations: {
        // do animations
        print("ANIMATING---")
    }, completion: { completed in
        // completion block
        print("COMPLETING---")
    }) 
}
```

Comment: You might want to mention this works in iOS 7 (and earlier), too. :) I'm not sure if that's clear…

Comment: Make sure the notification your registering for is UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, not UIKeyboardDidShowNotification

Comment: I tried these but still the animation doesn't work proper. I'm using self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement) instead of self.view.setNeedsLayout() self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints() does it matter?

Comment: Doesn't work in Swift 2 return the follow error: Value of type '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' has no member 'objectForKey'.

The solution is (aNotification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSTimeInterval)

Comment: @RafaelSachetto try "valueForKey(..."

Comment: The swift version works but should be:         guard let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {return}
        print(duration) // you got animation's duration safely unwraped as a double
        
        let curve = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as NSNumber //else do {return}
        print(curve)

Comment: to save 2 minutes to people like my future self:

double duration = [[aNotification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

UIViewAnimationOptions curve = [[aNotification.userInfo objectForKey: UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];

Answer (score 18):

The answer with the variable duration is right and work iOS 3 to 8, but with the new version of Swift, the answer's code is not working anymore.
Maybe it is a mistake on my side, but I have to write:

```
let duration = aNotification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as Double
let curve = aNotification.userInfo![UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as UInt

self.view.setNeedsLayout()
//baseConstraint.constant = 211
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions(curve), animations: { _ in
    //self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}, completion: { aaa in
    //(value: Bool) in println()
})
```

Looks like objectForKey is not working anymore and conversion is more strict.

Comment: I tried these but still the animation doesn't work proper. I'm using             self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement) instead of 
self.view.setNeedsLayout()
self.view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()

does it matter?

Comment: I do not understand where is your problem, but as now Swift is a clean code, I use it this way: 
        override func keyboardWillShow(note: NSNotification) {
        super.keyboardWillShow(note)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(note.animationDuration) {
            // Your changes
        }
    }

Comment: For Swift 2.2, I had to make two changes: for casting, you `as!` instead of `as`; and use `UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve)` instead of `UIViewAnimations(curve)`.

Answer (score 10):

swift3

```
    let duration = noti.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber
    let curve = noti.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! NSNumber

    self.view.setNeedsLayout()

    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), delay: 0, options: [UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: UInt(curve))], animations: {
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: How to change the duration.?

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 4 update, iOS 11+**

Register for the notification first in a view's lifecycle method :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}
```

Then in `keyBoardWillShow` method :

```
@objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    guard let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? Double else {return}
    print(duration) // you got animation's duration safely unwraped as a double
}
```

Finally, don't forget to remove observer in `deinit` method :

```
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, the selected answer is the right way to go.

More can be provided here is what the animation really is. If you print all CAAnimations in the UIViewAnimation block, you'll find that **it's a CASpringAnimation** when setting the animation curve to the one provided in keyboard notification. The duration is 0.5, and other parameters are:

```
let ani = CASpringAnimation(keyPath: someKey)
ani.damping = 500
ani.stiffness = 1000
ani.mass = 3
ani.duration = 0.5
```

The code above can reproduce the animation precisely.

Once animation curve is set to the keyboard one, UIView animation will ignore the duration in the parameter. (If you really want to change the duration, adjust the `mass` value.)

Comment: Did you query this from the existing animation?

Answer (score 4):

**Solution for Swift 5**

```
let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt

UIView.animate(
       withDuration: duration,
       delay: 0.0,
       options: UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: curve),
       animations: {
           self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
       }
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Right solution for Swift 5

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

and then

```
@objc func keyboardWillChange(notification: NSNotification) {

    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }

    let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
    let targetFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue

    self.bottomConstraint.constant = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - targetFrame.origin.y

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

// first of all declare delegate in your class UITextFieldDelegate

//Place at the top of the view controller

```
 // ****************** Keyboard Animation ***************
var animateDistance = CGFloat()
struct MoveKeyboard {
    static let KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION : CGFloat = 0.3
    static let MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION : CGFloat = 0.2;
    static let MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION : CGFloat = 0.8;
    static let PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT : CGFloat = 216;
    static let LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT : CGFloat = 162;
}
//
```

//Copy and pest textfields delegate method in you class

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    let textFieldRect : CGRect = self.view.window!.convertRect(textField.bounds, fromView: textField)
    let viewRect : CGRect = self.view.window!.convertRect(self.view.bounds, fromView: self.view)
    let midline : CGFloat = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height
    let numerator : CGFloat = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MoveKeyboard.MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height
    let denominator : CGFloat = (MoveKeyboard.MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MoveKeyboard.MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height
    var heightFraction : CGFloat = numerator / denominator

    if heightFraction > 1.0 {
        heightFraction = 1.0
    }
    let orientation : UIInterfaceOrientation = UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarOrientation
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientation.PortraitUpsideDown) {
        animateDistance = floor(MoveKeyboard.PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction)
    } else {
        animateDistance = floor(MoveKeyboard.LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction)
    }

    var viewFrame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animateDistance
    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)
    UIView.setAnimationDuration(NSTimeInterval(MoveKeyboard.KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION))
    self.view.frame = viewFrame
    UIView.commitAnimations()
}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
    var viewFrame : CGRect = self.view.frame
    viewFrame.origin.y += animateDistance

    UIView.beginAnimations(nil, context: nil)
    UIView.setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState(true)

    UIView.setAnimationDuration(NSTimeInterval(MoveKeyboard.KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION))

    self.view.frame = viewFrame

    UIView.commitAnimations()

}
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out something that tripped me up while solving this issue. I needed the **size** of the keyboard due to the new "quickype" view and its ability to show/hide (iOS8 only). This is how I ended up solving it:

```
- (void)keyboardWillChangeFrame:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSValue *value = notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
    self.keyboardFrame = [value CGRectValue];

    NSTimeInterval duration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    //ANIMATE VALUES HERE
}];
```

}

Comment: Note: You receive KeyboardWillShow event on "quicktype" view collapse/expand, curve and duration = 0 in that case. The size passed along with UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey key and is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
//--------------------------------------------------------------
// MARK: -
// MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
//--------------------------------------------------------------
//To trigger event when user types in fields
//right click in IB and choose EditingChanged >> textField_EditingChanged
//NOTE IF KEYBOARD NOT SHOWING IN SIMULATOR and no view appearing ITS TURNED OFF BY DEFAULT SO YOU CAN TYPE WITH YOUR MAC KEYBOARD - HIT CMD+K or Simulator > Menu > Toggle Software Keyboard...

@IBAction func textField_EditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    //if more than one search
    if(textField == self.textFieldAddSearch){
        appDelegate.log.error("self.textFieldAddSearch: '\(self.textFieldAddSearch.text)'")
        if textField.text == ""{

        }else{
            callJSONWebservices(textField.text)
        }
    }else{
        appDelegate.log.error("textFieldDidBeginEditing: unhandled textfield")
    }
}

//TWO WAYS TO HIDE THE VIEW
//textFieldShouldReturn
//buttonCancel_Action

//USER HIT RETURN BUTTON ON keyboard >> resignFirstResponder >> triggers  keyboardWillHide
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField)-> Bool{

    //triggers keyboardWillHide: which also fades out view
    self.textFieldAddSearch.resignFirstResponder()

    return false
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
// MARK: -
// MARK: - KEYBORAD
//--------------------------------------------------------------
private func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications() {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}

private func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
}
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let heightKeyboard = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().height {
            if let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.doubleValue {

                self.viewAddNewSearchResults.alpha = 0.0
                self.viewAddNewSearchResults.hidden = false
                if let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.integerValue {

                    appDelegate.log.info("keyboardWillShow: duration:\(duration)")

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay:0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut,
                        animations: {
                            //self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, Geo.width(), Geo.height() - height)
                            self.viewAddNewSearchResults_BottomConstraint.constant = heightKeyboard;
                            self.viewAddNewSearchResults.alpha = 1.0
                        },
                        completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let heightKeyboard = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue().height {
            if let duration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.doubleValue {
                if let curve = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]?.integerValue {

                    appDelegate.log.info("keyboardWillHide: duration:\(duration)")

                    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration, delay:0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut,
                        animations: {
                            self.viewAddNewSearchResults_BottomConstraint.constant = 0;
                            self.viewAddNewSearchResults.alpha = 0.0
                        },
                        completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

//Add button shows search result panel below search text fields
//just set focus in the textField
//then the keyboardWillShow will fade in the view and resize it to fit above the keyboard
//and match fade in duration to animation of keyboard moving up
@IBAction func buttonAdd_Action(sender: AnyObject) {

    //triggers keyboardWillHide: which also fades out view
    self.textFieldAddSearch.resignFirstResponder()
}

//TWO WAYS TO HIDE THE VIEW
//textFieldShouldReturn
//buttonCancel_Action

//Cancel on the search results - just resignFirstResponder >> triggers keyboardWillHide: which also fades out view
@IBAction func buttonCancel_Action(sender: AnyObject) {
    //triggers keyboardWillHide: which also fades out view
    self.textFieldAddSearch.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4**

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)

 func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
      let duration = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
      print("duration",duration)
 }
```