# Adding UITextField above Keyboard

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-to-add-toolbar-above-keyboard) how to create tool bar above keyboard. But I don't use any textfield that I need to tap and show keyboard. My idea is press on "Leave comment" button and then keyboard with a text field will be appeared.

So in the link I've attached they seems use inputAccessoryView of text field you interact with. But in my case I don't have any text field.

So first of all I need to toggle keyboard without text field and then show keyboard with a textfield like a bar above keyboard. How can I make it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18957476/ios-7-keyboard-animation/19236013

The link was very helpful for me when I did the same job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello you need to put your `UITextfield` outside the View,
like this:

[image]

ViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *_myTextField;
```

ViewController.m

```
UITextField *t = [UITextField new];
[self.view addSubview:t];
[t becomeFirstResponder];
t.inputAccessoryView = _myTextField;
```

see the result:
[image]

Comment: hi thank you for answer, but also as a part of question it's how to create text view above keyboard.

Comment: I mean a textfield above the keyboard. that added to keyboard as a tool bar view

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander, so??! my code is very answering to the question!! have you try it?